# Using system date in Laravel input validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to create a few validation rules for an input form using Laravel 4.x and I have also go the Validator service from Laracasts.

Is there any way to use the current year, taken from the system date, and use that in the rules?

For example, I want to create a rule that says that the year entered in the input form does not exceed the current year (i.e : I cannot put in 2015 or any higher year as of this day)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
'date' =>  array('min:'.date('Y'), 'max:'.date('Y'), 'date_format:"Y"');
```

Something along that line.. Catch my drift though right?

**Note:** This is untested.

**PS:** If for arguments sake you have a different format than just the year, you could split the inputs just for the validation.

```
$input = Input::only('date');
$input['date-year'] = date('Y', strtotime($input['date']));
//And then the validation rule will look something like this...
$rules['date-year'] =  array('min:'.date('Y'), 'max:'.date('Y'), 'date_format:"Y"');
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new validation rule like this:

```
// Less than equal
Validator::extend('lte', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if ( (float) $value <= (float) $parameters[0] )
        return true;
});
```

Use the new rule

```
$input = array('year' => 2015);

$rules = array('year' => 'lte:'.date('Y'));

$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```